# Is there any way to speed up the predicting process for tensorflow lattice?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, machine-learning, predict, tensorflow2.x

I build my own model with Keras Premade Models in tensorflow lattice using python3.7 and save the trained model. However, when I use the trained model for predicting, the speed of predicting each data point is at millisecond level, which seems very slow. Is there any way to speed up the predicting process for tfl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to improve speed, but they may involve a tradeoff with prediction accuracy. I think the three most promising options are:

- Reduce the number of features
- Reduce the number of lattices per feature
- Use an ensemble of lattice models where every lattice model only gets a subsets of the features and then average the predictions of the different models (like described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lattice/tutorials/canned_estimators))

Answer (score 0):

As the lattice model is a standard Keras model, I recommend trying [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). It optimizes your model by converting to Intermediate Representation (IR), performing graph pruning and fusing some operations into others while preserving accuracy. Then it uses vectorization in runtime. OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware, but it should work with any CPU.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Keras model to OpenVINO. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets are below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Save your model as SavedModel**

OpenVINO is not able to convert the HDF5 model, so you have to save it as SavedModel first.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from custom_layer import CustomLayer
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'model')
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device, e.g., CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what the best choice for you is, use AUTO. If you care about latency, I suggest adding a performance hint (as shown below) to use the device that fulfills your requirement. If you care about throughput, change the value to THROUGHPUT or CUMULATIVE_THROUGHPUT.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="AUTO", config={"PERFORMANCE_HINT":"LATENCY"})

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.